# Wordpress restAPI?

Tags: wordpress, api

Is there now an official wordpress restAPI integration or I have to use some of from the provided plugins what are many of theme?

I remember that they wanted to integrate one of the plugins in the core but now I do not find nothing googleing over and over.

If I have to use one of the plugins which should be that?

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API ?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ ?

I would like to use it to get my custom post types and use it with ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

This is official plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

And this is api guide

http://v2.wp-api.org